# R interaction() truncated after write and read csv file

Tags: r

I use the interaction() function to create and new variable and combines "Study" number (e.g. 1,2,3) and "Subject" number (e.g. 1:20). When I write my data frame to a csv and read it in another script this variable changes in the following way:
1.10 converts to 1.1 or 1.1 converts to 1.10 and 
2.10 converts to 2.1 or 2.1 converts to 2.10

It also happens in this simple code that I wrote:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
y <- 1:15

xy <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
xy$xy <- interaction(x,y)

xy

write.csv(xy, "xy.csv")
xy2 <- read.csv("xy.csv")

xy2
```

Is there a way to solve it easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly read in the column as a character rather than let R guess the data type since it looks so much like a decimal number

```
write.csv(xy, "xy.csv", row.names=FALSE)
xy2 <- read.csv("xy.csv", colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","character"))
```

you could also change the separator used for interation to make it look less like a decimal number

```
xy$xy <- interaction(x,y, sep="-")
write.csv(xy, "xy.csv", row.names=FALSE)
read.csv("xy.csv")
```

Comment: You may also consider
`xy_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y));
tidyr::unite(xy_df, xy, x, y, remove = FALSE)`.

`tidyr::unite` will produce a character whereas `interaction` creates a factor by default.

Comment: @Peter Whether it's a character or factor doesn't matter when you use `write.csv`. They both write out the same. The problem is that when you go pack to read the data with `read.csv`, R attempts to guess the data type based on observed values.

Comment: good point.  I suppose the point of my prior comment should have been the default separator for `tidyr::unite` is "_" whereas the default for `interaction` is "."